# Error looking up method on jsrender, using jsrender / jsviews with typescript

Tags: typescript, webpack, typescript-typings, jsrender, jsviews

I am trying to integrate/use jsview/jsrender in a typescript project with build done using webpack-4. Since the jsrender/jsviews package installed via npm does not contain type definitions not are they available via DefinitelyTyped but the author(s) of jsview/jsrender have provided the type definitions separately. I saved them in typings/[jsrender, jsview] folders and modified my tsconfig.json as shown below:

My tsconfig.json has the following:

```
{
"compileOnSave": true,
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": false
},
"include": [
    "static/js/**/*",
    "*/static/ts/**/*.ts"
],
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
],
"files": [
    "./typings/jsrender/index.d.ts",
    "./typings/jsviews/index.d.ts"
]
```

}

And I import jsrender with:

```
import * as jsrender from 'jsrender';
```

And when I try to use jsrender with:

```
tmpl = jsrender($).templates('Name: {{:name}}');
```

The webpack complains with the following error:

> TS2339: Property 'templates' does not exist on type
>   'JQuery'.

The first few lines of type definitions for jsrender has the following:

```
/// <reference types="jquery" />

declare module 'jsrender' {
    export = jsrender;
}

declare const jsrender: JQueryStatic;

interface JQueryStatic {
    /* var htmlString = $.render.templateName(data, myHelpersObject); // Render named template */
    render: {
        [tmplName: string]: JsViews.TemplateRender;
    };

    /* $.views.xxx ... // JsRender/JsViews APIs */
    views: JsViews.Views;

    /* $.templates(...) or $.templates.templateName: Compile/get template */
    templates: JsViews.Templates;
}
```

I am not sure why does webpack complain even though when debugging, if I just do:

```
let tmpl = jsrender($);
```

and put a breakpoint on the line above, I can see that the tmpl object does have the "templates" function available.

I am not sure if it is a webpack issue, tsconfig issue or the way I am using jsrender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, those versions of JsRender index.d.ts and JsViews index.d.ts are not correct, for your webpack + typescript scenario.

JsRender index.d.ts should start like this:

```
declare module 'jsrender' {
    export = jsrender;
}

declare const jsrender: ((jquery?: JQueryStatic) => JQueryStatic) & JQueryStatic;

// ********************************** JsRender **********************************

interface JQueryStatic {
...
```

and JsViews index.d.ts should start like this:

```
declare module 'jsviews' {
    export = jsviews;
}

declare const jsviews: ((jquery?: JQueryStatic) => JQueryStatic) & JQueryStatic;

// ********************************** JsObservable **********************************

interface JQueryStatic {
...
```

With those changes, things should work correctly.

Here is how you might code your .ts file, if using JsRender and loading jQuery as a module, rather than globally:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery'; 
import * as jsrender from 'jsrender'; 

jsrender($); // load JsRender jQuery plugin methods

let tmpl = $.templates(...);

// Now use tmpl.render() etc.
```

In fact jsrender($) returns $, so the above simpler syntax is equivalent to your version, (and in fact does not run up against the typescript declaration error issue you hit).

If using JsViews, you instead write

```
import * as $ from 'jquery'; 
import * as jsviews from 'jsviews'; 

jsviews($); // load JsRender and JsViews jQuery plugin methods

let tmpl = $.templates(...);

// Now use tmpl.render() and/or tmpl.link() etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I guess it should work. Just that I ditched jsrender/jsviews as their syntax seemed too complicated. I ended up sending pre-rendered html from server instead of returning Json. Not the best thing to do but works for me.